# The last cell in a tableview cell should not be deleted when trying to remove from array in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Entering data into textfield, when clicked on add button then that textfield text gets appended into an array and is displayed in table cell. Now max 5 data i can append and show it in a cell which is working but in a cell there is a delete button which deletes the data appended. Now i want that when deleting the entry from cell one by one, the last remaining data in a cell should not be deleted and a toast message should be displayed saying that mandatory data cannot be deleted. Right now i am removing the data at a given index but all data is being deleted right now beacuse i dont know which condition to put for last cell not being deleted. Please help me

My code :

```
var rowIndex = Int()

@objc func deletecontact(sender: uibutton)
{
   rowIndex = sender.tag
   Self.openDeleteDialogPopup()
}

IBAction weak var func yesBtnClicked(sender:uibutton)
{
   MyArr.remove(at: rowIndex)
   Mytableview.reloaddata()
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried as a [example]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function where you are deleting the item from the array you need to check on if it has a count greater than 1 or not, if it is not, then you show the toast. If it is then you delete the row

```
@IBAction weak var func yesBtnClicked(sender:UIButton) {
   guard MyArr.count > 1 else { //If we have more than one item, then don't enter the else block
   //showToastHere
    return
   }
   MyArr.remove(at: rowIndex)
   MyTableview.reloadData()
}
```